# I want to Create a function named VALIDATE_EMP which accepts employeeNumber as a parameter, Returns TRUE or FALSE depending on existence

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

Sample Data

```
create table Employees (emp_id number, emp_name varchar2(50), salary number, department_id number) ;

insert into Employees values(1,'ALex',10000,10);
insert into Employees values(2,'Duplex',20000,20);
insert into Employees values(3,'Charles',30000,30);
insert into Employees values(4,'Demon',40000,40);
```

Code :

```
    create or replace function validate_emp(empno in number)
    return boolean
    is lv_count number
    begin
    
    select count(employee_id) into lv_count from hr.employees where employee_id = empno;
    if lv_count >1 then
    return true;
    else
    return false;
    end;
```

I want to Create a function named `VALIDATE_EMP` which accepts `empno` as a parameter, Returns `TRUE` if the specified employee exists in the table name “Employeee” else `FALSE`.

Comment: It seems that you created it. So, what's the problem?

Comment: Shouldn't the check be for *at least one* employee, not *more than one*? By the way, I would just `return lv_count > 0;` and save a few lines of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- missing semi-colon as terminator of the local variable declaration
- if user you're connected to isn't `hr`, remove it (otherwise, leave it as is)
- column name is `emp_id`, not `employee_id`
- missing `end if`

When fixed, code compiles:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION validate_emp (empno IN NUMBER)
  2     RETURN BOOLEAN
  3  IS
  4     lv_count  NUMBER;
  5  BEGIN
  6     SELECT COUNT (emp_id)
  7       INTO lv_count
  8       FROM employees
  9      WHERE emp_id = empno;
 10
 11     IF lv_count > 1
 12     THEN
 13        RETURN TRUE;
 14     ELSE
 15        RETURN FALSE;
 16     END IF;
 17  END;
 18  /

Function created.

SQL>
```

---

How to call it? Via PL/SQL as Oracle's SQL doesn't have the Boolean datatype.

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    result boolean;
  3  begin
  4    result := validate_emp(1);
  5
  6    dbms_output.put_line(case when result then 'employee exists'
  7                                 else 'employee does not exist'
  8                            end);
  9  end;
 10  /
employee does not exist

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

Maybe you'd rather return `VARCHAR2`; then you'd *mimic* Boolean, but you'd be able to use it in plain SQL:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION validate_emp (empno IN NUMBER)
  2     RETURN VARCHAR2
  3  IS
  4     lv_count  NUMBER;
  5  BEGIN
  6     SELECT COUNT (emp_id)
  7       INTO lv_count
  8       FROM employees
  9      WHERE emp_id = empno;
 10
 11     IF lv_count > 1
 12     THEN
 13        RETURN 'TRUE';
 14     ELSE
 15        RETURN 'FALSE';
 16     END IF;
 17  END;
 18  /

Function created.

SQL> select validate_emp(1) from dual;

VALIDATE_EMP(1)
-------------------------------------------------------------------
FALSE

SQL>
```

Comment: How will I get boolean values in output after calling this function i.e it should return true or false. So, how to call this function

Comment: Edited; have a look.

Comment: Employee 1 does exist, though.